# gnuplot, rotating xtics at 90 degree

Tags: gnuplot

How can I rotate xtics at 90 degree using gnuplot. Below I tried it but it gives me strange results (xticks need to be shifted downward). Any idea?

```
set terminal pngcairo  transparent enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 600, 400 
set output 'datastrings.2.png'
set key fixed right top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitle columnhead nobox
set label 1 "Generate plot labels from first row in each column" at graph 0.02, 0.85, 0 left norotate back textcolor rgb "#56b4e9"  nopoint
set label 2 "Generate x-axis labels from first column in each row" at graph 0.02, 0.8, 0 left norotate back textcolor rgb "#56b4e9"  nopoint
set style data linespoints
set xtics  norangelimit 
set xtics   ()
set xtics rotate by 90
set title "Auto-labeling plots from text fields in datafile" 
set xrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set x2range [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set ylabel "mm" 
set yrange [ 0.00000 : 200.000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set y2range [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set zrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set cbrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set rrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
NO_ANIMATION = 1
## Last datafile plotted: "ctg-y2.dat"
plot 'ctg-y2.dat' using 2:xticlabel(1) index 2,      ''           using 2 index 3
```

[image]

Comment: What are "strange results"? How should we judge if you don't show the results? How should we reproduce your results if you don't show the data? Please edit your question and show your data or at least your resulting graph! See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `help xtics`, there is the possibilty to right align your labels.
Just for illustration "August" is not abbreviated in order to demonstrate the right alignment of the rotated text.

**Code:**

```
### right align xtic labels
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Jan 1
Feb 2
Mar 3
Apr 4
May 5
Jun 6
Jul 7
August 8
Sep 9
Oct 10
Nov 11
Dec 12
EOD

set xtics rotate by 90 right

plot $Data u 2:xtic(1) w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Size of plotted data and xtics is not same. i have done it only at some positions.

Comment: @Shahgee ??? What do you mean? That you used `index 2`? Does the above example answer your question or not?

Comment: The above was just an example. Real data is Data(200,5)//rows , col and then I have an other vectors; 1: xtick_position (10,1 ) and 2: xtick_text (10,1 ) . I donot know how to use this command . I tried  set xtics 'xticks.txt' using 1:2, but it donot work.

Comment: @Shahgee I'm confused.... please edit your question and show some (minimized) **real** data! How should we make suggestions if we don't know what you **really** have?